# Cant get hibernate to update object without EntityExistException being thrown

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to do a bidirectional one to one relation and when updating the AccountExtrasModel on the first save it works fine but when updating I get either an error or the sql statements adds an insert and then a delete instead of an update.

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class AccountModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Account_ID;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "accountModel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private AccountExtrasModel accountExtras;

    public AccountModel addExtras(AccountExtrasModel accountExtrasModel) {
        accountExtrasModel.setAccountModel(this);
        this.setAccountExtras(accountExtrasModel);
        return this;
    }
}

import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "AccountExtras")
public class AccountExtrasModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ID;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private AccountModel accountModel;

    @Lob
    private String description;
    private String[] myVideos;
    private String[] likedVideos;
    private String imageReference;
}
```

If i change the @MapsId to @JoinColumn in AccountExtrasModel then i get the desired result but what its doing is inserting a new row and linking it to acccount and then deleting the old row instead of doing an update.

This is the error im getting:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-26T18:19:01.657+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.alttube.account.models.AccountExtrasModel#1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.alttube.account.models.AccountExtrasModel#1]",
    "path": "/update_account"
}
```

What can i do to get the desired result which is to simply perform an update on the accountExtrasModel to the corresponding account to which it belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update an `AccountModel` instance by setting a new instance of `AccountExtrasModel`, as you do in `addExtras()`, then it is normal to have a delete+insert. By updating the id you would end with orphaned records.

When you set new values on `AccountExtrasModel` instance, check if `accountExtras` is initialized. If not, do the `addExtras()` stuff. If it is, do not replace it, just change it, so hibernate will generate an update on the extras table (but keep the record id unchanged).

Comment: Thanks! cant believe i didnt notice that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use the method ***save*** try use the method ***merge***, because in case of object exist in database the framework will update this object.
Case the object don't exist, the framework will insert as normal.

Regards!